# How to display group data separately using DataList in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datalist

I have a sql table which have the following data,

```
Id   City      Country 
---  ------    ------------
1    Delhi     India
2    New York  United States
3    Karachi   Pakistan
4    Mumbai    India
5    Lahore    Pakistan
6    Kanpur    India
7    Delhi     India
8    Mumbai    India
```

Now, I want to display the above data in my web app as displayed below;

```
India
Delhi (2)    Mumbai (2)    Kanpur (1)    

United States
New York (1)

Pakistan
Karachi (1)    Lahore (1)
```

Please tell me:

- The SQL query which will fetch the data as I want. I want City, Country and Count (grouping of all cities)
- And how to display the fetched data in the format I given above in ASP.NET C#. Is there any control which we can use to display the data as I want. Or we have to write any customized code, if customized code then please tell me the code for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL should be

```
select country,city,count(city)
from dbo.location 
group by country,city order by country
```

Then use datarepeter to display your data. Follow this [link](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/d89d1d96-03f1-4784-bbb2-a3db1af393f5/aspnet-datalist-and-data.aspx)

Comment: any reason why he has to use a Repeater instead of a DataList?

Comment: based on his grouped display country>>data

Answer (score 2):

You can use a DataSet, normalize your DB, read two tables into it and then display it with two nested DataRepeater, just like two for-loops would do.