# Displaying search results in a Website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a website where i need to search for items from database and display it in page.I am using `Datalist` for displaying all the items .Now i need to display all the items according to some category.For example if i search for a `two-wheeler` it may have many categories or manufacturer's.Now I want to display it separately according to the categories.I can use many datalist to do that,but it will slow down the site.Instead which control can i use to do this.I searched the web but got no idea.So please give me sugessions to go about it.Any sugessions will be appreciated.

**Code**:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="Dlitems" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  RepeatColumns="4"
                        CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="15">
         <ItemTemplate>
              <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgbtnProductImage" CssClass="imgdisp" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>'
                                                    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ProductCode") %>' runat="server" CommandName="cmdView" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                       <table>
                           <tr>
                              <td width="20px"></td>
                              <td>
                                             <img src="../Database/images/inr.jpg" alt="addtocart" />
                                             <asp:Label ID="lblproductprice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>' CssClass="lbl" />
                                           </td>
                              <td>
                                              <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnaddtocart" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="25px" ImageUrl="~/Database/images/addtocart.JPG"
                                                                ToolTip="Add to Cart" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ProductCode")+","+ Eval("ProductName")+","+ Eval("ImagePath")+","+ Eval("Price")+","+ Eval("LongDescription") %>'
                                                                CommandName="addtocart" />
                                            </td>
                           </tr>
                       </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: You can get category name from db. Use order by category in query or sp. In item_databound, check if current record's category is diiferent than last record, put some space or line or css in current record.

Comment: @Hiral can't get you.can u give some code..

Answer (score 0):

> You should go for a `Repeater` control.
>
> Example on [Repeater](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/01/repeater-control-example-in-aspnet.html)

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgbtnProductImage" CssClass="imgdisp" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePathForTwoWheeler")%> + <%# Eval("ImagePathForCategory") %>'
                                                CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ProductCode") %>' runat="server" CommandName="cmdView" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: alrite, so lets say u search for Ducati which will have categories 125 cc, 250 cc, 500 cc....is this your scenario??

Comment: and will it be imagebutton?

Comment: check my updated answer. try it out and lemme know if any issues.

Comment: I dont want to display only images.I have  details of the products in database which i want to display as i have shown in my code above.Tell me the changes which i can make in my code to split the products according to category.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25754/discussion-between-praveen-nambiar-and-smith269)

Answer (score 0):

You can take benefit of `gridview`.
 
Bind you gridview data.
And letter merge the rows.
For an example you can use the below link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34337/How-to-merge-cells-with-equal-values-in-a-GridView

### Edit 1

Some links

[How to display group data separately using DataList in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523345/how-to-display-group-data-seprately-using-datalist-in-asp-net)
http://aspnettuts.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/asp-net-repeater-group-recordsdata-delete-selected-rows/